# Commands out of sync while calling stored procedure Mysql

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

i have two store procedures, i needed to page the record (say select every next `n` records) to the first one which select all matching records is.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `trans_all`(IN varphone VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
  Select
  loans.amt,
  loans.date,
  loans.pay_period,
  borrower.phone As borrower_phone,
  borrower.name As borrower_name,
  lender.phone As lender_phone,
  lender.name As lender_name,
From
  loans Left Join
  users borrower On borrower.id = loans.borrower_id Left Join
  users lender On lender.id = loans.lender_id
Where
   (lender.phone = varphone) or (borrower.phone = varphone);
END
```

i then get the count in php ;like this

```
$result = $mysqli->query(sprintf("call trans_all('%s')",$phone));
$num_recs = $result->num_rows;
```

then i needed to select precise records to i do do this

```
$result = $mysqli->query(sprintf("call trans_history('%s','%s','%s')",$phone,$start,$limit));

$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // this like gives the error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

the second stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `trans_history`(IN varphone VARCHAR(15), IN page INT, IN items INT)
BEGIN
  Select
  loans.amt,
  loans.date,
  loans.pay_period,
  borrower.phone As borrower_phone,
  borrower.name As borrower_name,
  lender.phone As lender_phone,
  lender.name As lender_name,
From
  loans Left Join
  users borrower On borrower.id = loans.borrower_id Left Join
  users lender On lender.id = loans.lender_id
Where
   (lender.phone = varphone) or (borrower.phone = varphone)  LIMIT page , items;
END
```

what could be cause this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPs return second resultset which contains the status. You need to use `next_result()` before you make subsequent queries.

```
$result = $mysqli->query(sprintf("call trans_all('%s')",$phone));
$num_recs = $result->num_rows; 
$result->close();
$mysqli->next_result(); // <- you need this before you make another query

//Then make call second SP
$result = $mysqli->query(sprintf("call trans_history('%s','%s','%s')",$phone,$start,$limit));
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$result->close();
$mysqli->next_result();
```